# How do I get into the array I got from json?

Tags: javascript, fetch, fetch-api

I have a JSON file. I'm pulling data from this file with fetch. But I want to get the first element in all the elements of the array I pulled. I tried this but couldn't find it. Can you help me ?

MY JSON DATA :

```
{
    "cols": [
        "Name Surname",
        "Company",
        "Email",
        "Date",
        "Country",
        "City"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            "Hyacinth Vincent",
            "Duis Corporation",
            "iaculis.enim@magnaCrasconvallis.ca",
            "28/06/2022",
            "Eritrea",
            "Lyubertsy"
        ],
        [
            "Brenden Martinez",
            "Volutpat Nunc Associates",
            "iaculis@estMauris.org",
            "24/03/2021",
            "British Indian Ocean Territory",
            "Colwood"
        ],
        [
            "Lunea Kinney",
            "Ornare Facilisis Eget Incorporated",
            "rutrum.eu@liberoMorbiaccumsan.ca",
            "20/10/2021",
            "Jordan",
            "Yorkton"
        ],
        [
            "Rhona Mooney",
            "Sed Et PC",
            "placerat@sodalesat.ca",
            "10/11/2020",
            "Azerbaijan",
            "Shrewsbury"
        ]
    ]
}
```

MY JS CODE :

```
fetch("api/tesodev.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    let cols = data.cols;
    let responseData = data.data;
  for (let index = 0; index < responseData.length; index++) {
    let newResponseData = responseData.map(function (el, i) {
        console.log(el[i]);
      });
      
  }
    console.log(cols[0]);
  });
```

Exactly what I'm trying to do is to get to the first elements of all the elements of the data array.
I want to access the data of "Hyacinth Vincent", "Brenden Martinez", "Lunea Kinney", "Rhona Mooney".

Comment: Do you want to create a new array like `["Hyacinth Vincent", "Brenden Martinez", "Lunea Kinney", "Rhona Mooney"]`?

Comment: ```const names = res.data.map((row)=>{
 return row[0];
})
console.log(names);```

Comment: I will use the data I reach to search from the search input. do you think this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the current row in your for loop, then access the first element of this row.

```
fetch("api/tesodev.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    let cols = data.cols;
    let responseData = data.data;
    for (let index = 0; index < responseData.length; index++) {
      const myDataRow = responseData[index];
      const theFirstDataOfMyRow = myDataRow[0];
      console.log(theFirstDataOfMyRow); 
    }
    console.log(cols[0]);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked well for me :)

Comment: So, can I use the data I get from here in a scope other than fetch?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you're doing wrong is mapping over the whole child array and logging every part of it, when what you want is the first element:

```js
const data = {
  "cols": [
    "Name Surname",
    "Company",
    "Email",
    "Date",
    "Country",
    "City"
  ],
  "data": [
    [
      "Hyacinth Vincent",
      "Duis Corporation",
      "iaculis.enim@magnaCrasconvallis.ca",
      "28/06/2022",
      "Eritrea",
      "Lyubertsy"
    ],
    [
      "Brenden Martinez",
      "Volutpat Nunc Associates",
      "iaculis@estMauris.org",
      "24/03/2021",
      "British Indian Ocean Territory",
      "Colwood"
    ],
    [
      "Lunea Kinney",
      "Ornare Facilisis Eget Incorporated",
      "rutrum.eu@liberoMorbiaccumsan.ca",
      "20/10/2021",
      "Jordan",
      "Yorkton"
    ],
    [
      "Rhona Mooney",
      "Sed Et PC",
      "placerat@sodalesat.ca",
      "10/11/2020",
      "Azerbaijan",
      "Shrewsbury"
    ]
  ]
}

let cols = data.cols;
let responseData = data.data;
for (let index = 0; index < responseData.length; index++) {
  console.log(responseData[index][0])
}
```

(I would **strongly** suggest you change your data format; an array of objects would be much less fragile:

```
    ...
    "data": [
        {
            name: "Hyacinth Vincent",
            company: "Duis Corporation",
            email: "iaculis.enim@magnaCrasconvallis.ca",
            date: "28/06/2022",
            country: "Eritrea",
            city: "Lyubertsy"
        },
        {
          ...
```

Comment: I think so too but this is a recruitment case :)

Comment: This was a test question for a job application?  Please don't use stack overflow to cheat; if you can't answer this one on your own you're not qualified for the job.

Comment: I'm not cheating. This is an internship application. They said I was free to get help.

Answer (score 2):

ummm...

I think there are multiple problems in this
newResponseData will be array of item having values undefined as console.log() returns undefined.

I think this two lines can help.
Can you check at your end

```
 let responseData = data.data;
  const finaldata = responseData.map(item => item [0])
```

Comment: Thanks for checking it out...would you mind it marking this answer to be correct

Answer (score 1):

You can use a double index to access the first field. `[i][0]` will access the first field in the `i`th object,

```
let responseData = <json>;

for (let index = 0; index < responseData.length; index++) {
    console.log(responseData[i][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost doing it the way you want it work.

```js
const data = {
    "cols": [
        "Name Surname",
        "Company",
        "Email",
        "Date",
        "Country",
        "City"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            "Hyacinth Vincent",
            "Duis Corporation",
            "iaculis.enim@magnaCrasconvallis.ca",
            "28/06/2022",
            "Eritrea",
            "Lyubertsy"
        ],
        [
            "Brenden Martinez",
            "Volutpat Nunc Associates",
            "iaculis@estMauris.org",
            "24/03/2021",
            "British Indian Ocean Territory",
            "Colwood"
        ],
        [
            "Lunea Kinney",
            "Ornare Facilisis Eget Incorporated",
            "rutrum.eu@liberoMorbiaccumsan.ca",
            "20/10/2021",
            "Jordan",
            "Yorkton"
        ],
        [
            "Rhona Mooney",
            "Sed Et PC",
            "placerat@sodalesat.ca",
            "10/11/2020",
            "Azerbaijan",
            "Shrewsbury"
        ]
    ]
}

// Simplyfied, get data, use only data, only putput first entry in the array.
data.data.forEach((person) => {
  console.log(person[0])
})

// Would be something like this:
/*
fetch("api/tesodev.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    let cols = data.cols
    let persons = data.data
    for (i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
      console.log(persons[i][0])
    }
  })
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked well for me :)